# Direct2D Leak over RDP

Tags: winapi, rdp, direct2d

This is a weird behaviour on which I 'd need your experience.

I have a Direct2D app which draws the screen in a typical way:

```
// fact,draw global factory and ID2D1RenderTarget, WM_PAINT creates them once.

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    RECT rc = {};
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    if (!fact)
        D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE::D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED, &fact);
    if (!draw)
    {
        D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES hp;
        hp.hwnd = hWnd;
        hp.pixelSize.width = rc.right;
        hp.pixelSize.height = rc.bottom;
        fact->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top)), &draw);
    }
    draw->BeginDraw();
    .. more paint
    draw->EndDraw();
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

This app has also a self-debugging library which displays the number of handles the app creates.
When the app is run locally, no problem, the number of handles remain static.

On running the app over Remote Desktop, I get 10 more handles per second. When the app is running for a few minutes I get 10000 handles.

Further debugging shows me that between `ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw()` and`EndDraw()` the leaks occur, even if I don't draw anything.

Anyone has experienced such an issue yet? Is this a known bug?

Comment: ValidateRect(), try to use this function,
The BeginPaint function automatically takes effect for all client areas. The system continues to generate WM_PAINT messages until the current update area takes effect.